# Button variable cannot be referenced from a static context error

Tags: java, static, compiler-errors

How do I prevent this error from happening with my current code? I apologize for my logic being very amateur.

```
 public class jButExmp {    
 JFrame exmpFrame;
 JButton Button1, Button2, Button3;    
 public jButExmp ()  {
     exmpFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     exmpFrame.setSize(250,150);
     exmpFrame.setVisible(true);
     exmpFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     exmpFrame.add(Button1);
     exmpFrame.add(Button2);
     exmpFrame.add(Button3);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
 exmpFrame = new JFrame ("Example Frame");
 Button1 = new JButton ("1");
 Button2 = new JButton ("2");
 Button3 = new JButton ("3");

 Button1.setSize(80, 30);  //set size of button
 Button1.setLocation(0,0);
 Button1.setEnabled(true);

 Button2.setSize(80,30);
 Button2.setLocation(90, 0);
 Button2.setEnabled(false);

 }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the error?

Comment: in which line you get error?

Comment: the first line of the main method

Comment: `Button2.setSize(80,30);
 Button2.setLocation(90, 0);`  Don't do that - it will cause many problems.  Use layouts.

Comment: It seems that is not the exact source used, because when I try to compile it, the compiler reports.. `exmpFile.java:6: invalid method declaration; return type required
 public jButExmp ()  {`

Comment: @AndrewThompson i changed the class name on accident :x i'll change it back

Comment: *"i changed the class name on accident"*  You also stomped on my edits when you hit the back button to alter the post.  Instead use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14271915/edit) below the post!

Answer (score 1):

[image: ExmpFile screen shot]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ExmpFile {

    JFrame exmpFrame;
    JButton Button1, Button2, Button3;

    public ExmpFile()  {
        exmpFrame = new JFrame ("Example Frame");
        Button1 = new JButton ("1");
        Button2 = new JButton ("2");
        Button3 = new JButton ("3");

        Button2.setEnabled(false);

        exmpFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        // better to pack() to the size of content..  BNI
        exmpFrame.setSize(250,150);
        exmpFrame.setVisible(true);
        exmpFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        exmpFrame.add(Button1);
        exmpFrame.add(Button2);
        exmpFrame.add(Button3);

        exmpFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ExmpFile();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the invokeLater and for actually compiling and running the thing. -1 for lack of encapsulation :-(

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek *"lack of encapsulation"*  Huh?

Comment: Yes, exactly - try looking it up - it's one of the basic tenets of object oriented design.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to access not static variables in static main method, so it will compilation errors.

Try this

```
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class jButExmp {
    JFrame exmpFrame = new JFrame("Example Frame");
    JButton button1, button2, button3;

    public JButton getButton1() {
        return button1;
    }

    public void setButton1(JButton button1) {
        this.button1 = button1;
    }

    public JButton getButton2() {
        return button2;
    }

    public void setButton2(JButton button2) {
        this.button2 = button2;
    }

    public JButton getButton3() {
        return button3;
    }

    public void setButton3(JButton button3) {
        this.button3 = button3;
    }

    public jButExmp() {
        exmpFrame = new JFrame("Example Frame");
        exmpFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        exmpFrame.setSize(250, 150);
        exmpFrame.setVisible(true);
        button1 = new JButton("1");
        button2 = new JButton("2");
        button3 = new JButton("3");
        exmpFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        exmpFrame.add(button1);
        exmpFrame.add(button2);
        exmpFrame.add(button3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jButExmp jButExmpRef = new jButExmp();

        jButExmpRef.getButton1().setSize(80, 30); // set size of button
        jButExmpRef.getButton1().setLocation(0, 0);
        jButExmpRef.getButton1().setEnabled(true);

        jButExmpRef.getButton2().setSize(80, 30);
        jButExmpRef.getButton2().setLocation(90, 0);
        jButExmpRef.getButton2().setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: This will compile and run, but is really bad style

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek what should i do instead?

Comment: have given some refactor to Class.

Comment: @Jay - see my separate answer

Answer (score 0):

This woud be the more idiomatic way to do it, though this code has some other problems, including the fact that you're not setting up button3 the way you are with button1 and button2, and the fact that you are setting the locations of the buttons while using the default FlowLayout (which doesn't support setting positions).

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class JButExmp extends JFrame {  

    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;

     public JButExmp (String title)  {

         super(title);

         button1 = new JButton("1");
         button2 = new JButton("2");
         button3 = new JButton("3");

         add(button1);
         add(button2);
         add(button3);

         button1.setSize(80, 30);  //set size of button
         button1.setLocation(0,0);
         button1.setEnabled(true);

         button2.setSize(80,30);
         button2.setLocation(90, 0);
         button2.setEnabled(false);

         setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         setSize(250,150);
         setVisible(true);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args)  {
         JButExmp jButExmp = new JButExmp("Example Frame");
     }
}
```

Comment: i originally had code to make it invisible, but i felt that would be futile to keep in considering it doesn't do much. i'll remove it immediately!

Comment: Why extend frame?  What functionality are you adding or changing?  See [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) (I might say 'look it up' but instead you can just 'follow the link').  -1